# Arduino IDE complilation error http.begin

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

im trying to program  my nodemcu v3 esp8622 board to send notification via IFTTT webhook, when pir sensor decects motion. Im getting this error:

`Compilation error: expected primary-expression before ',' token`

I tried looking up httpClient library examples, and other questions but i dont get answer to this specific problem.

Event trigger link works perfectly, this is my code.

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "internetdom";   // Your WiFI ssid
const char* password = "JCjmpi1z";  // Your WiFi password
boolean PIRstate;                   // variable to store PIR state
boolean lastPIRstate = HIGH;
int PIR = 7;  // PIR connected to GPIO 4, NodeMCU pin D2

void setup() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
  }

  pinMode(PIR, INPUT);  // digitalWrite(PIR, LOW);

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

  delay(30000);
}

void loop() {
  PIRstate = digitalRead(PIR);  // HIGH when motion detected, else LOW

  if (PIRstate != lastPIRstate)  // Checking if there is any motion
  {
    Serial.println("Motion Detected");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)  // Check WiFi connection status
    {
      HTTPClient http;  // Declare an object of class HTTPClient

      http.begin(
          WiFiClient,
          "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/lot_Motion_Sensor/with/key/"
          "kT9aCIo2VjjYNioqabtneAoQl5kRK2sZIUVv4wfjOC5");  // Specify request
                                                           // destination
      http.GET();  // Send the request
      http.end();  // Close connection
    }
    lastPIRstate = PIRstate;
  }
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\sketch_mar16a\sketch_mar16a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\sketch_mar16a\sketch_mar16a.ino:43:28: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
   43 |       http.begin(WiFiClient, "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/lot_Motion_Sensor/with/key/kT9aCIo2VjjYNioqabtneAoQl5kRK2sZIUVv4wfjOC5");  //Specify request destination
      |                            ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: expected primary-expression before ',' token

Comment: you can't use the type WiFiClient as parameter to http.begin. look better at the examples